# Completeness spanning trees

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, graph-algorithms

A spanning tree of a graph is called a completeness tree if the set of 
its leaves induces a complete subgraph in the host graph. Given a graph $G$ 
and an integer $k$, what is the complexity of deciding if $G$ contains a 
completeness tree with at most $k$ leaves?

A reason for asking this question is that the corresponding problem for 
[independency trees](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X96003068) 
is NP-complete, here an independency tree is a spanning tree such that the set of its 
leaves is an independent set in the host graph.

Another reason is [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140200/on-super-connected-graphs) 
(and the corresponding answers). It turns out that *every* spanning tree of $G$ is a completeness tree 
if and only if $G$ is a complete graph or a cycle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a triangle-free graph, a completeness tree must be a Hamiltonian cycle (minus one of its edges). [ISGCI](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_371.html) says Hamiltonian cycle is NP-complete in triangle-free graphs. Therefore, so is finding a completeness tree (regardless of any restriction on max number of leaves).

Comment: Oh, this is a nice observation, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I cannot beat David in the elegance of his answer. But after spending al lot of time on thinking about this problem I 
would like to betray my solution to you though ;)

Let $k \ge 2$ be a fixed interger. Given $G$, construct $H$ as follows:Take two copies $G_1$, $G_2$ and a clique $Q$ on $k$ vertices $x, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{k-1}$, a new vertex $y$,
fix a vertex $v_1 \in G_1$ and a vertex $v_2 \in G_2$. 
$H$ is obtained from $G_1, G_2, Q$ and $y$  by joining  $x$ to $v_1$, joining $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{k-1}$ 
to $v_2$ and joining all neighbors of $v_1$ in $G_1$ and all neighbor of $v_2$ in $G_2$ to  $y$.

Then it can be easily seen that $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle if and only if $H$ has a completeness tree with at most $k$ leaves.